# \cite in 2 line in the same cell

Tags: tables, cite-package

I am trying to write a `tabular` in which the second column contains some references (`\cite{}`). The result obtained is a unique line for each cell, and I would like to fit the reference in 2 line, in order to have a length comparable to the others.

How can I do?

the code is the following and the picture is what I obtained.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{caption,setspace}
\usepackage{quoting}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{booktabs, array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\quotingsetup{font=small}
\captionsetup{font={small,stretch=1}}

\begin{document}


\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1cm}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\small\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1cm}}
\begin{tabular}{C{1.7} M{2} C{2.5} C{2.2} C{1.6} C{2}}
\toprule
        {\bf Type of crop} & {\bf Reference} & {\bf Location}\\
\midrule
{\bf Rice} &        {\cite{Lugato:2013}} &  {Northern Italy}\\
{\bf Maize} &       {\cite{Uzoma:2011}} &   {Tottori, Japan}\\
{\bf Maize} &       {\cite{Oguntunde:2004}} &{Ejura, Ghana}\\
{\bf Soyabean} &    {\cite{Tagoe:2008}} &   {Gifu, Japan}\\
\bottomrule
\end {tabular}

\include{biblio}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Tesi}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you refrain from using the `m` specifier in your table.  How do you like a layout like this?  Also note that you specify six columns in your table head.

> [image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs, array, tabularx}
\usepackage{lmodern, natbib, ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\small\hspace{0pt}\RaggedRight}p{#1cm}}
\newcolumntype{B}[1]{>{\small\hspace{0pt}\RaggedRight\bfseries}p{#1cm}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\small\hspace{0pt}\RaggedRight}l}

\begin{tabular}{@{}B{1.7} P{2} L@{}}
  \toprule
  \mdseries Type of crop & Reference              & Location       \\ \midrule
  Rice                   & \citet{Lugato:2013}    & Northern Italy \\
  Maize                  & \citet{Uzoma:2011}     & Tottori, Japan \\
  Maize                  & \citet{Oguntunde:2004} & Ejura, Ghana   \\
  Soyabean               & \citet{Tagoe:2008}     & Gifu, Japan    \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[Lugato et al.(2013)]{Lugato:2013} Lugato et al.(2013).
\bibitem[Uzoma et al.(2011)]{Uzoma:2011} Uzoma et al.(2011).
\bibitem[Oguntunde et al.(2014)]{Oguntunde:2004} Oguntunde et
  al. (2014).
\bibitem[Tagoe et al.(2008)]{Tagoe:2008} Tagoe et al.(2008).
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```